# Flex Mobile: Swipe and ToggleSwitch gesture confusion

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, swipe, gestures, flex4.6

I am trying to use swipe gesture in my mobile app to move between views, and followed the tutorial from here:

http://www.flex-blog.com/using-swipe-gestures-in-mobile-flex-application-air-for-android/

It works, but: I have many ToggleSwitch components in my views and iOS confuses the Toggle Switch button slide with a swipe: every time I move the switch, it takes me to the previous / next view.

I have tried to add a gestureSwipe="donothing()" to the toggleswitch and toggleswitch container, but it does not make a difference.

I am working with FB 4.6 and testing on iOS 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
if (event.target is ToggleSwitch) {
    //do nothing
} 
else 
{
    if (event.offsetX == 1) {
        navigator.popView();
    } else {
        navigator.pushView();
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to check and see which "target" aka the component the event originated from is NOT a ToggleSwitch or any other component.

**EDIT: It may be currentTarget instead of target but I am pretty sure it is target.**